Can a blown step down module destroy the whole circuit?
I am currently building an Rc car which I designed myself.
Yesterday I started testing the whole system, including four motors (one in each tire), 5 servos (MGN995, 4 ontop the suspention, one steering), and a small 9g servo for the rear spoiler.
The motors are controlled by a speedybee 60A ESC, and a Arduino Mega is the brain of the whole thing.
To supply power, I have a 8A step down converter, converting the 12V from the LiFe Batteries (2x 12V 20A discharge) to 7V for the whole system. Lastly, I have a Radiomaster r88 Receiver for controlling the whole thing, and a Adafruit BNO055 sensor to eliminate roll with the suspention servos.
When I throttled up the motors (750kv, 6.5A stall current) the receiver started giving weird numbers. It should put out a PWM signal from 1000 to 2000, but suddenly there was something like 13000 and 6, so I told the firmware on the Arduino to disregard any of theise bad numbers. Every time one of the ununsual numbers would appear, the motors would throttle down, the next receiver value would be valid again, then the motors would throttle up (to the commanded value), drawing to much of something, then confusing the receiver into giving bad numbers, motors throttle down etc. This sometimes would end in a oscillation (thottle up, throttle down, throttle up, etc). The only thing stopping this, was me cutting the power to the system.
After some testing and adjusting the firmware, the step down module made a loud bang, and something there "exploded" (there was something similar to an explosion) ontop of the capacitors. I immidiatly cut power. What the heck just happened there?
I ripped out the step down module, but after further examination there is visually nothing wrong with it. I replaced it with a fresh one, but after turning everything back on, there was just nothing (exept the power bank powered Arduino).
I examined the receiver and servos individually, and it turns out that 5/6 servos died, and the receiver. However again, there was nothing visually wrong with any component.
Now I could go ahead and replace all this stuff, just for everything to explode again.
What could be the cause of this?
One theory I have, is that the ESC had interduced lots of electrical noise, and the step down module did't like that. I read somewhere online that converters don't like when the input voltage fluctuates fast.
Is this possibility?
I am a student in 13 grade, and I have 6 hours of Mecanical/Electrical engineering at school. Most of my knowledge from the internet. So there might be a super stupid answer that I just don't know.
Thanks for you help!
Edit: Currently the servos are not connected, since im changing them out right now




Anyone will ask you for at least a sketch of the system, without which it is impossible to even hazard an answer.

A picture of your setup will help quite a bit.

aside: i would avoid using dupont connectors, or any other loose push-on connectors, with something that moves around. Those don't hold very strongly and i can imagine one popping off in the worst place and time, in a way that could be dangerous from a human on/or fire safety viewpoint. At least hotglue them all down before using...

@aside yes! This is only for prototyping. I want to switch to two Arduino nanos, and solder everything. Thank you for the tip!

UPDATE: I have looked at your added pictures, thank you for putting them in.
As I suspected, you have many wires longer than necessary running all over, which besides voltage drops also induces unwanted currents and voltages in them, as well as noise, leading to unpredictable behavior and possible failure.
Remember this: short and neat wiring is not only nicer to look at, it is also better for the circuits and their proper and reliable functioning.
Bent or coiled wires will pick-up or radiate more unwanted currents and voltages than the straight wires.
A separate piece of advice regarding switching power supplies, especially buck converters:
because they (and typically their single switching transistor inside) are the only "line of defense" or separation between the destructively high input voltages for the typically sensitive lower-voltage circuits down the line from them, and because they frequently fail "short", a good practice is to use a linear voltage regulator after them which can withstand the full input voltage without failing, and thus protect the lower voltage circuits.
Buck converters are typically used to provide the minimum voltage needed for those linear regulators, while the linear regulators provide the stable and far less noisy voltage to the more sensitive circuits or components.
You could also use a fuse at the input or the output of a buck converter, combined with an SCR "crowbar" which would make a short and burn the fuse out if the buck output voltage goes above safe limits.
If the input voltage is above the absolute maximum that the 5V circuits can withstand (usually is) and the step-down converter gets shorted, it will most likely burn them out.
Large and fast fluctuations in input voltage can affect the step-down converter, but not if it has a large enough capacitor on its input AND output.
Regardless of a powerful battery supplying it, large loads can introduce significant voltage ripples, especially if there is a length of wire involved to produce significant voltage drops.
A way to isolate such drops is to place a diode in series with the step-down converter, and then a decently sized capacitor to smooth out any ripples at its input.
Additionally, due to large and fast current changes in your wires, it is possible you have a significant "ground loop" problem where voltage spikes get induced in your "ground" wires, so even if the +V supply is kept regulated, the problem "comes up" from the ground which is supposed to be zero, but it can go up to sometimes unpredictable values.

What do you mean by "and the step-down converter gets shorted"? You mean that 12V goes in the 5V circuit?

@Vaynexx_ That would be a very possible failure mode for most buck converters.

Why do they get shorted? Too much current?
I have looked at the buck converter with my oscilloscope and the chip is dead

@Vaynexx_ The high side switch transistor can fail for many reasons: overvoltage, over current, too much power dissipation (temperature too high), manufacturing defect,...  If it shorts out then the input voltage will run right trough it, the inductor becomes a piece of wire at DC, straight to the output...

@Unimportant uhh, ok, that makes sense. Thanks!

@Vaynexx_ My apologies, I could and should have been more clear in my descriptions, but fortunately you already got good answers from our helpful pals here. Any semiconductor (diode, transistor, etc.) can fail "open" or "short". If a current surge through it and the conductive material is too thin to withstand it and insulated from the rest of the semiconductor die, it will break like a bridge and fail "open". If voltage gets large enough to break down extremely thin insulation, or the current "fuses" or melts the material in such a way that it creates a conductive bridge, it fails "short".

@Vaynexx_ The short then acts almost like a piece of wire of low resistance and conducts the current through, either to ground, to the output, or to any other pin on a chip. The action of very fast on and off switching in your regulator combined with inductor and capacitor gives you the lower voltage on the output. If switching stops and the "switch" part of the IC stays on, the inductor no longer behaves as a reactive element which suppresses rising of the current through it, but it becomes like a simple piece of wire with very low resistance, allowing almost all of the input current through.

@Vaynexx_  ...to the output, and thus the output voltage rises up to the value of the input voltage, damaging or destroying any circuits which can't withstand it.

@Vaynexx_  By the way, besides marking my answer as "Accepted", you can also "up-vote" it by clicking on the UP arrow. We get additional points for that. Thank you.

Thank you all for helping me! I really appreciate it! Where do you learn this stuff? Do you just have to blow up electronics until you start thinking about seafty?

@Vaynexx_ Plenty of reading up, asking questions, analyzing, searching for answers or learning more when I get stuck, and yes, sometimes things fail or burn and then I search for the answer to why and how, also years of experience. The Internet is full of information, but sometimes it's not easy to find it. And no, you have to blow up electronics until you start learn about safety; typically the safety is the first thing you should learn in any potentially dangerous or lethal kind of work, and while you may ignore it with low voltages and low powers in electronics, you definitely shouldn't....

@Vaynexx_  ...ignore it when dealing with voltages above about 80+ volts or significant powers, because you may lose your life when current goes through you, or a finger or an eye when a component like an electrolytic capacitor or large semiconductor explodes in your face. But sometimes you burn a component or a board here and there, and then you learn the steps you missed.
